# Learn on/through the internet?

Tags: prepositions

In one of my tests, a question was like this-

We can now learn _ the internet. What will be the appropriate word in the gap?

1. Through
2. On

I am thinking that "on" will be the correct answer. But I am not quite sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Internet** by definition means an inter-connected system of computer networks.

Though both the options are correct and can fit the sentence well, the preposition *on* is more likely used.

[Google Ngram Viewer Reports](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2019&smoothing=3&content=on%20the%20internet%2Cthrough%20the%20internet%2Cfrom%20the%20internet%2C%20over%20the%20internet&corpus=26&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20internet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthrough%20the%20internet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrom%20the%20internet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cover%20the%20internet%3B%2Cc0)

In fact, other than these two prepositions, the most commonly used ones are *over* and *from* (in this referral context).

> People can learn so many creative new things **on/over/from/through** the internet these days.